# DrawerContent does not exist in my Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I was looking at a tutorial titled creating a menu or NavigationDrawer, which said to use drawerContent in a scaffold, but I don't have anything called drawerContent in Jetpack Compose and Jetpack Compose's libraries under any title! Help me please. Should I use an implementation?

```
@Composable
fun hi(){
    Scaffold {
        drawerContent = { Drawer() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Named arguments have to be inside of the round brackets, like this: `Scaffold(drawerContent = {}) {}`

Answer (score 1):

`drawerContent` is removed from `Scaffold` in `material3`. If you want to use `drawerContent` then you may use `material` or you can use `ModalNavigationDrawer` available in `material3`, but for that you have to use `Scaffold` as content in `ModalNavigationDrawer`.

Checkout this solution for better understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75019927/19212377

Update:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun SimpleTopAppBar() {

    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
    val items = listOf(Icons.Default.Close, Icons.Default.Clear, Icons.Default.Call)
    val selectedItem = remember { mutableStateOf(items[0]) }

    ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {

            ModalDrawerSheet {
                Spacer(Modifier.height(12.dp))
                items.forEach { item ->
                    NavigationDrawerItem(
                        icon = { Icon(item, contentDescription = null) },
                        label = { Text(item.name) },
                        selected = item == selectedItem.value,
                        onClick = {
                            scope.launch { drawerState.close() }
                            selectedItem.value = item
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(NavigationDrawerItemDefaults.ItemPadding)
                    )
                }
            }


        },
        content = {

            Scaffold(
                topBar = {
                    TopAppBar(
                        title = {
                            Text(
                                "Simple TopAppBar",
                                maxLines = 1,
                                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                            )
                        },
                        navigationIcon = {
                            IconButton(onClick = { scope.launch { drawerState.open() } }) {
                                Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu,
                                    contentDescription = "Localized description"
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    )
                },
                content = { innerPadding ->
                    LazyColumn(
                        contentPadding = innerPadding,
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
                    ) {

                    }
                },
                floatingActionButton = {
                    FloatingActionButton(
                        onClick = {
                            Intent(
                                applicationContext,
                                text::class.java
                            ).also { startActivity(it) }
                        },
                        containerColor = BottomAppBarDefaults.bottomAppBarFabColor,
                        elevation = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.bottomAppBarFabElevation()
                    ) {
                        Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "Localized description")
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I found it, now how to work with it

Comment: How should I text you? The text of the menus is actually the text of the icons

Comment: I apologize for asking so many questions because I'm new to Android and I'm new